# Learn BLoC directly or should I first learn GetX, Provider or Riverpod to understand BLoC better

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, riverpod

I am trying to learn BLoC without learning any other State Management libraries like GetX, Riverpod, Provider, etc., Learning BLoC is confusing, I don't know how BLoC runs in an App. What should I do? like first try to learn other State Managers or Stick to BLoC eventually I get it.

What is easier to learn Riverpod or BLoC? at least in 10 Days.

I am trying to learn the BLoC from YouTube, an 11-hour course. It has been 2 days & got a general Idea but eventually, I have to work on a Real Project. I am not getting how to learn it fast & effectively. I fear that if I don't get the BLoC or am unable to understand it effectively, I will not be able to code the app.

[Here is the YouTube video I am referring to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mn254cnduOY&t=6531s&ab_channel=VandadNahavandipoor)

Even though this guy is explaining how to test the BLoC, I am not able to understand how & what he is doing, there are so many classes & override codes. Even my test code results are always getting failed but his getting passed.

Should I create notes for effective learning like Handwritten notes or Word document notes?

Comment: Start small, learn provider which is suitable for small projects and then move to riverpod.  BLoc is best suited for big and complex projects.  GetX is easy to learn if  you grasp the basics of provider but won't recommend it if you're just start your journey with state management.

Comment: Actually, I am an intern in a company, and they want there app in Riverpod or BLoC.

Comment: go with riverpod

Comment: This falls in the category of "opinionated question". There's no objective answer to this. Some folks will tell you one thing and others will tell you another. This sort of question shouldn't be asked on StackOverflow based on its rules. You may want to ask on Reddit or Discord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same case when i start learning the BloC, I watched many videos and read the c of the BloC library (  https://bloclibrary.dev/#/  )

What I notice that wathcing videos and read documentaion is not enouth.

I start building demo app and started practicing what i learned and what cases i didn't find on youtube i started fixing these problems, at this point my understanding for BloC now is better.

The answer for your question is NO you don't need to learn any state management to learn BloC.

All what you need is the patience, searching and practice practice ..

I hope my answer is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Bloc might seem like a daunting task at first but once you get the hang of it, your journey ahead is a breeze. Also, you do not need to know any other state management solutions to learn bloc. I learned Bloc first and then Provider,Getx,Riverpod etc. If you know the basic concept and need of a state management solution, learning Bloc in a weeks time should be more than achievable(if you put true and honest effort that is).
Good luck for you journey ahead. Stay motivated and keep learning.
Cheers.